# Pytorch deepcopy of model

Tags: pytorch

I would like to save and re-load a model in my code using deepcopy.
The line is simply

> backup_model = copy.deepcopy(model)

However, I get the error trace

> RuntimeError: Only Tensors created explicitly by the user (graph
> leaves) support the deepcopy protocol at the moment

My Pytorch version is 1.11.0.
I don't understand my mistake. According to this "https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/can-i-deepcopy-a-model/52192", what I am doing is correct.

Comment: Is your model on GPU? Try making the copy from CPU. You also could make a copy of the parameters instead, which would be the same thing, if you have the model architecture.

Comment: I copied the parameters instead, thank you for the tip. It's weird though because I've seen this exact code dozens of times.